# prorgress bar show half on some devices

Tags: android, android-progressbar

My progressbar shows a full circle in android 2.2 to 4.0, but in android version 4.1 is shows a half circle.

Below 4.0 device is show full progressbar (ex https://i.stack.imgur.com/9o9DY.jpg) but when I test app on 4.1 is shows up like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTE1q.jpg

Both devices are the same height and width, so why is only half showing on 4.1 devices??

```
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#E5E5E5"
android:orientation="vertical" >

  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/layoutbordercolor" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/btnback"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="3dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/back" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bitmap"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.5"
        android:src="@drawable/logostar" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="12dp"
            android:text="San Diego Unified"
            android:textColor="#603311"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:text="SCHOOL DISTRICT"
            android:textColor="#603311"
            android:textSize="10sp" />
     </LinearLayout>

     <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/options2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/options1" />
 </LinearLayout>

 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#E5E5E5"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
  </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/lytContent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="vertical" >
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/lytContent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/layout_border"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listMainMenu2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:dividerHeight="1dip"
        android:fadeScrollbars="true"
        android:listSelector="@color/listview_selector"
        android:paddingBottom="3dp"
        android:paddingLeft="3dp"
        android:paddingRight="3dp"
        android:paddingTop="3dp" 
        android:visibility="gone"

        />



</LinearLayout>

      <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lytContent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

   <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/prgLoading"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"

        android:paddingTop="100dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtAlert"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:text="@string/alert"
        android:textColor="@color/text"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:visibility="gone" />
    </LinearLayout>


  </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: no i edit my screenshot because in anotherdevice which is 4.1 progressbar show  only half circle

Comment: may b problem is on my xml layout check it i want to show progressbar center of screen before asyntask load data

Comment: please edit my xml code where is problem? all linearlayout are correct for height ??

Comment: On another phone I have here, I tested your app and there was no circle at all.

Comment: so why is show half circle?????

Comment: Is the half circle at the bottom of the screen?

Comment: maybe posting the code where you show the progress and do stuff with the other controls. I guess you switch the visibility of the textview and the progressbar and for android 4.1+ there might be some difference in the layout rendering. sidenote: I'd realy use RelativeLayout for this.